# How to split different data types in String[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, filereader

I would appreciate if someone could help me with my school project.
I have a txt file with names and phone numbers (ex. John Smith 1123456789). I need Java to read the file and load it into two separate array strings: one with first/last names and another with phone numbers. Please give me advise on how to do it right. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
         String book;
         FileReader reader;
         BufferedReader buffer;
         String line;
         String[] list;

    try {
        reader = new FileReader(book);
        buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
        list = new String[50];
        int x = 0;
        line = buffer.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            list[x] = line;
            line = buffer.readLine();
            x++;
        }
        buffer.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e)
```

Comment: What specific issue are you running in to?

Comment: If you really want to hold the hold file in memory like that, you should use an `ArrayList` so you don't have a hard-coded line limit.

Comment: Have you looked into [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: I am not worried about the array limit atm.. I want to get an idea of how to divide the string from the txt file into names and numbers (to separate them)

Comment: there is String.split(). read the docs !

Answer (score 2):

If you [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the `line` as follows -

```
String[] fields = line.split("\\s+"); // \\s+ means one or more space(s)
```

the result array `fields` will have 3 elements -

1. first name at index 0
2. last name at index 1
3. phone number at index 2

Currently, you don't seem to have the 2 arrays for storing the names and phones. Create those too, and populate them after every split.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that names/phone numbers on each line are in the same order. I'm also assuming (since this is a school project) that you know which separator is used between the names and the phone numbers. After reading the line, you can split it by using `String.split` using the separator. The two resulting parts will be the name and phone number, like this:

```
line = buffer.readLine();
String[] parts = line.split("\t"); // if tab is used as the separator
String name = parts[0];
String phoneNumber = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to create two `ArrayList`, split the line using String.split() and then insert them in the Lists.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
while (line != null){
    String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
    names.add(lineArray[0]);
    phoneNumbers.add(lineArray[1]);
}
String[] namesArray = (String[]) names.toArray();
String[] phoneNumberArray = (String[]) phoneNumbers.toArray();
```